# How to change values char

Tags: c++, char

I wrote this C++ code that compiles without errors, but after I have bugs. How can I make this work?

```
int main() {
int a=0;
for(a=0;a<=9;a+=1)
{
cout<<a<<"\n";
char ssss[] = "hello";
ssss[1]=a;
cout<<ssss<<"\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

Current output is:

[image]

Comment: ; or ;; it's same. Error start when I open this application.
I cannot post image. [link]http://s10.postimage.org/9t8xu8n55/Untitled.jpg

Comment: what result do you expect? If you assign an int value to a char, the  int will be evaluated as an ASCII code of a character. For example, 0 stands for '\0' and that will end an char*-style string so you will see only `h` in the first cycle. If you would like to see "h0llo" then you should write `ssss[1]=a+48;`, in which 48 is the ASCII code of char '0'

Comment: What's the purpose of this code? Let me know your intended output.

Comment: you can embed image like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/208637) . Note : add the image in question

Comment: `s/ssss[1]=a+48;` is better written as `ssss[1]=a+'0';` - there's really no need to use magic constants, _especially_ if you value portability.

Answer (score 3):

There's only a bug if it doesn't meet specifications. And, since you haven't *provided* specifications on how it should act, we have to guess.

When you set the character `ssss[1]` to the integer value `0` through `9`, that's *not* the character `'0'` through `'9'`, instead (at least in ASCII), it's some control characters, like `9` being the horizontal tab character.

This is likely to make your output look strange.

You can see this clearly in that, for 0, you get just `h` (since 0 is the string terminator).

For 1 through 4 and 6, you see the hex codes output. 5 is the `ENQ` character so I'm not sure what that's doing. 7 is the ASCII bell character so you should hopefully hear a beep, 8 is the backspace which is why `llo` overwrites the initial `h`, and 9 is horizontal tab, leading further output to start at the following tab stop.

If you want to use the *characters* `'0'` through `'9'`, change the `for` loop to:

```
for (a = '0'; a <= '9'; a++)
```

as per the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main (void) {
    char str[] = "hello";
    for (int code = '0'; code <= '9'; code++) {
        str[1] = code;
        std::cout << code << ": " << str << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
48: h0llo
49: h1llo
50: h2llo
51: h3llo
52: h4llo
53: h5llo
54: h6llo
55: h7llo
56: h8llo
57: h9llo
```

Comment: Yes! This is my solution! A lot of thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this will execute and give output like this

```
0 h 
1 hllo 
2 hllo 
3 hllo 
4 hllo 
5 hllo 
6 hllo 
7 hllo 
8 hllo 
9 h   llo
```

it is because when a =0, it assigns a null character to the end and hence output is h only. and at 9 it will put a `\t`(tab) in the place since ASCII of 9 equivalent to tab.